# rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py _port:=/dev/ttyACM0 on RasPi giving "could not open port /dev/ttyUSB0" error

Tags: ros, arduino, rosserial, rosrun, rosserial-python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed `rosserial_arduino` on my RasPi and my Arduino code for [**Push Button**](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Push%20Button) has been uploaded successfully.
To run the code, I am following the following steps as mentioned in the tutorial:

1. Startup roscore using `roscore`
2. Run the run the rosserial_python serial_node.py using `rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py _port:=/dev/ttyUSB0`
3. Watch button status on `rostopic echo pushed`

Now, the issue here is that when I try step 2 using `rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py _port:=/dev/ttyACM0` (my Arduino is on ACM0), the error message I receive is

`[ERROR] [WallTime: 1411295710.119812] Error opening serial: could not open port /dev/ttyUSB0: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/ttyUSB0'`

For some reason, it keeps taking `USB0` as the input even if I specify `ACM0` as the port. This error does not occur on my Ubuntu 14.04 distro running *Indigo*. My RasPi is running *Groovy*.
I have also added the necessary group permissions (adding user to `dialout`, etc.) but to no avail. Please suggest methods to solve this issue.

---

Thanks to ahendrix for having found out the problem. But there is a follow up issue [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/193183/rosserial_python-failed-packet-flags/). Please check.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193144/rosrun-rosserial_python-serial_node.py-_port:=/dev/ttyacm0-on-raspi-giving-%22could-not-open-port-/dev/ttyusb0%22-error/) by [Nightstalker](https://answers.ros.org/users/20256/nightstalker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2014-09-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think in the Groovy version, the serial port was passed directly as an argument, rather than as a ROS parameter. Try:

```
rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyACM0
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nightstalker](https://answers.ros.org/users/20256/nightstalker/) on 2014-09-22**:
You deserve a cookie. That worked.
But it gives an error of `Failed Packet Flags`. Any thoughts?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-09-22**:
I think the rosserial message format changed at some point. You should check that you're running a groovy version of the rosserial arduino library and the arduino sketch.

**Comment by [Nightstalker](https://answers.ros.org/users/20256/nightstalker/) on 2014-09-22**:
Yeah, I checked that. It's all groovy.

**Comment by [Nightstalker](https://answers.ros.org/users/20256/nightstalker/) on 2014-09-22**:
@ahendrix, please check [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/193183/rosserial_python-failed-packet-flags/)